# auto boxing and boxing of wrapper classes

Tags: java

in wrapper classes we have two types of methods parseXxx() and valueOf() in every wrapper class for interconversion between primitive and wrapper objects.recently java 1.5 introduced auto boxing and boxing.so why they didn't deprecate those methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Autoboxing and Auto Unboxing are just compile time features. Try writing something like this in your source file and then have a look at the decompiled code:

```
Integer i = 10;
```

Decompiled code:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(10);
```

Similarly,

```
int i = new Integer(100);
```

will give you the below when decompiled:

```
int i = (new Integer(100)).intValue();
```

Thus, the JVM still heavily relies on these methods at runtime, though it's masked when you write the code.

Comment: great i understood what is happening.But small help i never tried to see decompiled code how to see that?

Comment: @sateesh - just get a decompiler such as [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui) and all you've to do is drag and drop the generated .class file into this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, parseXxx() is entirely unlike boxing; it turns a *String* into a primitive object. valueOf(), on the other hand, is actually *used* in boxing -- it either constructs a new wrapper object, or it fetches an existing one from a cache, depending on the value. The Java compiler generates a call to valueOf(), and that's precisely what boxing *means*.

Comment: Friedman Hill ..can we tell in this way when there is unboxing java compiler generates a call to parseXxx() method.Is my previous statement correct?

Comment: No. As I said, parseXxx() translates from strings into wrapper objects; unboxing has nothing to do with Strings. unboxing means a call to doubleValue() or intValue() or floatValue(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. There can be value sometimes in explicitly stating some conversion (for the clarity of e.g. some unobvious/obscure case).
2. Wouldn't that deprecation result in old programs becoming excessively littered with deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 0):

As the command line arguments are treated as String Array, but given the condition when you are expecting command line argument other than String datatype(that may be primitives) i.e. boolean, int, byte, short, long, float, double, char than you need to parse the argument into the one what your program expects and here you use parseXXX() methods, to be precise parseXXX method take String argument and return the appropriate data type which you are trying to parse into.